# $_GET not retrieving anything

Tags: php, html, get

This is my URL: 'http://www.example.com/page?code=2028555689' but when I run this code:

```
echo '<script>alert("'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'");</script>';
echo '<script>alert("'.$_GET['code'].'");</script>';
```

The first alert box displays: `/page?code=2028555689`, however the second alert box is empty.

Why can't I retrieve the value of `code` using `$_GET`? The first alert box is to test whether there could be a problem with the `.htaccess` file and clearly there isn't.

Here are the contents of the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes

# Disable Automatic Directory detection
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect to www version of site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove page extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Remove index from URL
RewriteRule ^index$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the first line? Is this literally the code you have?

Comment: Code works fine for me. Create a new PHP file that just has these two lines of code along with `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: If I comment out the first line, then I just get a blank alert box.

Comment: My XSS senses are tingling...

Comment: `/page?` shouldn't that be `/page.php?` unless you've some rewrite happening. See if http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php shows anything and view HTML source and the console.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I use `.htaccess` to hide the `.php` extension.

Comment: What's the `.htaccess` rule you are using?

Comment: First, simplify: rather than relying on alerts, visit the page and **View source**.  Does the value show up there? Does ANYTHING show up there?  Second, before these two echos, throw in a `var_dump($_GET);` - what do you get?

Comment: Have you tried /page/?code=

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: @cale_b `var_dump($_GET);` produces `array(0) {}`

Comment: I can retrieve the data I need using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` so I'm just going to solve the problem by not using `$_GET`.

Comment: The problem probably has something to do with my pages being created dynamically by my custom 404 page. However, even when `var_dump($_GET);` gets called after the status has been set to 200, it still produces `array(0) {}`. I think the best solution is to not use `$_GET` at all. I already use `$_POST` 99% of the time anyway.

Comment: @OliverQueen I only use alert boxes for debugging, otherwise at the very least I would be using `htmlspecialchars` on the `$_GET` array. My site (Websemantica) will only go live after I have done extensive tests to make sure it is free of XSS vulnerabilities and any other possible security risks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason `$_GET` won't retrieve anything is because my 404 page dynamically generates the content. Even though I have written some code to generate a 200 status, `$_GET` still won't retrieve anything. The 404 page will always get called whenever there is no cached page present. The solution is simple, not use `$_GET`. I have it working now by calling `strtok` with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to retreive the `$_GET` data.